# Xamarin.Forms - Custom Logic For Enabling/Disabling iOS "Go" Key?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, iphone-keypad

I'm using Xamarin.Forms to build a login page. For the password field, I've set the Control.ReturnKeyType to UIReturnKeyType.Go ("Go" key). The default behavior is that if *any* character is entered into the field, the "Go" key is enabled. But I want to keep the "Go" key disabled if there are *only* spaces in the field. Is there a way to add custom logic for the enabling/disabling of the "Go" key?

**Note:** I realize that disallowing spaces in the field is one solution, but I need to allow spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iOS SDK does not have a way to programmatically enable or disable GO button based on some condition.